# Как вывести всю страницу одним print?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Пробовал сделать страницу с помощью python. Нашёл как сделать это множеством принтов и захотел попробовать все их объединить в один. Но вышла такая ерунда:

[image: Ерунда]

Вот код:

```
#!/Python380/python 
print(
    """
    Content-type: text / html

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Проба с Python</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1><b>Hello.</b></h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
)
```

Возможно ли вообще такое или это просто мои фантазии? XD

Comment: @mrEvgenX, да, уже понял что глупый вопрос задал по самой глупой ошибке XD Спасибо) Напишите ответ и я приму его)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вникая в [документацию по cgi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html).

Первая строка получается пустая, а пустая строка как раз отделяет заголовки от тела ответа. Из-за чего `Content-Type` перекочевал в тело, а заголовков будто вообще нет.

Плюс отступы между тройными кавычками, они тоже считаются частью выходной строки и ничего хорошего не добавляют.